# GPS prompt on app loading, "script name" instead of "app name" is displayed

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap

We have an app written in HTML/JS via PhoneGap that still have a badly formatted message that pop when the GPS is asked.

It compile perfectly on Android.

It render perfectly on iOS emulators (via Xcode) and it passes the Apple testers.

It render badly on iOS devices.

Screenshot here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkOAH.png

Does anyone have some experience on that? And can help how to overcome?

Comment: I believe you should paste your code for us to have a look

Comment: You need to look at the location permission strings that are in your info.plist. Presumably your build process is creating this file and doing so incorrectly